# Oracle :Invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle

Oracle throws invalid username/password when trying to login with a created user.
Oracle is installed locally.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYSTEM"
SQL> show con_name;

CON_NAME
------------------------------
ORCLPDB
SQL> CREATE USER intro_user IDENTIFIED BY mypassword;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT TO intro_user;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION, GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE TO intro_user;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO intro_user;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE TABLE TO intro_user;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select username from all_users where username like 'in%';

no rows selected

SQL> select username from all_users where username like 'IN%';

USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INTRO_USER

SQL> connect intro_user/mypassword
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>
```

I have also tried the below command to connect :

1. connect intro_user/mypassword@orclpdb  ==> not working.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `@orclpdb` points to the correct PDB in tnsnames.ora? What does "not working" mean? Did connecting with that specification return the *same* error, or a different one?

Comment: Is "mypassword" actually the password you used, or are you masking it from us? Is your real password mixed case? Are you using double quotes around it? What is the setting of SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER and the instance parameter SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON ?